# Coroutines and Asynchronous commands in Unity, Encryption and Decryption. How to make this function run asynchronosly to the rest of my code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, encryption, coroutine

I am working on a project that requires encryption and decryption of downloaded files. Some of these files are quite large. I need a way to do these functions asynchronously. For some reason, this code is causing a complete slowdown on the machine when they are called. Instead of doing the task in the backend, the machine drops all tasks and freezes up while doing encryption and decryption.

Here is the code in question.

```
            string encryptedFilePath = Path.Combine(FolderPath, SessionData.instance.email + "/", download.FileName + ".mp4");
            yield return StartCoroutine(DownloadManagementPage.instance.EncryptFile(originalFile, encryptedFilePath));
            DownloadManagementPage.instance.DeleteFile("TEMP.mp4");
```

```
public IEnumerator EncryptFile(string srcFilename, string destFilename)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Encrypting");
        Debug.LogError("Source " + srcFilename);
        Debug.LogError("Destination " + destFilename);
        var aes = new AesManaged();
        aes.BlockSize = aes.LegalBlockSizes[0].MaxSize;
        aes.KeySize = aes.LegalKeySizes[0].MaxSize;
        byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltKey);
        var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(SKey, salt, Iterations);
        aes.Key = key.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
        aes.IV = key.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        ICryptoTransform transform = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

        using (var dest = new FileStream(destFilename, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(dest, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (var source = new FileStream(srcFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                {
                    source.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
                }
            }
        }

        yield return null;
        Debug.LogError("Done Encryption");
    }

    public IEnumerator DecryptFile(string srcFilename, string destFilename)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Decrypting");
        Debug.LogError("Source " + srcFilename);
        Debug.LogError("Destination " + destFilename);
        var aes = new AesManaged();
        aes.BlockSize = aes.LegalBlockSizes[0].MaxSize;
        aes.KeySize = aes.LegalKeySizes[0].MaxSize;
        byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltKey);
        var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(SKey, salt, Iterations);
        aes.Key = key.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
        aes.IV = key.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        ICryptoTransform transform = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

        using (var dest = new FileStream(destFilename, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(dest, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var source = new FileStream(srcFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                    {
                        source.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
                    }
                }
                catch (CryptographicException exception)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Decryption failed.", exception);
                }
            }
        }

        yield return null;
        Debug.LogError("Done Decryption");
    }
```

I thought that having the code in a coroutine would work but it didn't work the same as my other coroutines. I also tried the async keywords as well as source.CopyToAsync(cryptoStream) but I have no idea how those would work in this context.

=======EDIT=======
I managed to get the Copy to Async function working

```
    public async Task EncryptFileAndDeleteOriginal(string srcFilename, string destFilename)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Encrypting");
        Debug.LogError("Source " + srcFilename);
        Debug.LogError("Destination " + destFilename);
        var aes = new AesManaged();
        aes.BlockSize = aes.LegalBlockSizes[0].MaxSize;
        aes.KeySize = aes.LegalKeySizes[0].MaxSize;
        byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltKey);
        var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(SKey, salt, Iterations);
        aes.Key = key.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
        aes.IV = key.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
        FileStream source = new FileStream(srcFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        FileStream dest = new FileStream(destFilename, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(dest, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        Task task = source.CopyToAsync(cryptoStream);
        await task;
        source.Close();
        dest.Close();
        Debug.LogError("Finished Encryption");
        //DeleteFilePath(srcFilename);
        Debug.LogError("Deleted Original");
    }
```

Comment: From the docs:  `However, it’s important to remember that coroutines aren’t threads. Synchronous operations that run within a coroutine still execute on the main thread.`  The work can be spread across multiple frames using the `yield` keyword.  Each time you yield, you are saying "lets pick up where we left off next frame".

Comment: How do you propose I fix my code so that the operations run in the background (don’t stop the rest of my applications operations just to do encryption or decryption)

Comment: using async code instead.  [Asynchronous Coding C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)

Comment: I managed to make this asynchronous, editing the post with my updates.